# Howto make "update-grub" to ignore guest volumes on a KVM Hypervisor?

Tags: grub2, virtualization, lvm, kvm-virtualization

I have some Ubuntus acting as a KVM Hypervisor and, every time I run "update-grub" on those servers, it takes a lot of time to finish and makes too much disk IO.

I'm seeing that it tries to find others O.S. but, each "extra" logical volume I have, belongs to my guests, there is no need to scan those volumes...

So, how can I configure update-grub to ignore some LVM2 Logical Volumes?

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

Try editing /etc/defaults/grub

```
sudo -e /etc/defaults/grub
```

Add the line:

> GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"

Save your edits and re-run update-grub

FWIW, I have used physical partitions with KVM in the past and IMHO it causes more problems then it is worth and I did not see any performance boost. Consider using virtual disks, they have a number of advantages including cloning and portability. YMMV, good luck.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that using virtual disks doesn't fix this issue, because grub quite happily scans LVM volumes. I use LVM to manage my VM's backing store, rather then physical partitions, and I also have grub go and spend a long time scanning all the LVM volumes.